# Add integer to Backbone model attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am attempting to allow for a button to be clicked on a form and its number of votes be +=1. You'd think I could do something like idea.set({"votes": +=1}) but it doesn't seem to like that. I made an event to listen for a click on my upvote button, now I'm stuck. Can anyone help?

```
    IdeaVoter.Views.IdeasIndex = Backbone.View.extend(

    template: HandlebarsTemplates['ideas/index'],
    initialize: function(){
    this.collection.on('reset',this.render, this)
    this.collection.on('add',this.render, this);
     },

   events: {
    "submit #new_idea ": "createIdea",
    "click #upvote": "upvote"
        },

  render: function(){
    $(this.el).html(this.template())
    this.collection.each(this.addIdea)
    this.collection.each(this.upvote)
    return this;
  },

  addIdea: function(idea){
    view = new IdeaVoter.Views.Idea({model: idea})
    $('#ideas').append(view.render().el)
  },

  upvote:function(idea){
    idea.save()
  }


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for a simple

```
idea.set('votes', idea.get('votes') + 1);
```

You probably want to add a method to your model to hide that behind a simple `idea.upvote()` or the like.